# FB CTF - SyntaxError: Grunt is not generating JS Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, gruntjs

Installing prod: https://github.com/facebookarchive/fbctf/wiki/Installation-Guide,-Production

This is the error message that I am getting when I try to install by any given method(direct,docker and vagrant):

[+] Running grunt to generate JS files
/var/www/fbctf/node_modules/grunt-legacy-log-utils/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js:106
...styles,
^^^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/fbctf/node_modules/grunt-legacy-log-utils/index.js:12:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
-> # apt remove nodejs
-> # curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
-> # sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Probably, if it is not version 12, an error appears

Answer (score 1):

Was working on getting FBCTF up, tried to search everywhere but no one has a fix. Found a fix myself.

```
nano package.json
```

In package.json, change from

```
"grunt": "^1.0.1",
```

to

```
 "grunt": "1.0.1",
```

The "^" seems to update the version of grunt to 1.3.0 (As of writing this) which apparently is not compatible with the FBCTF which have not been maintained for 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows install the latest version of [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and the error should disappear.